# Spring LockRegistryLeaderInitiator making excessive calls in some lock registry implementations

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm currently working with LockRegistryLeaderInitiator:

`org.springframework.integration.support.leader.LockRegistryLeaderInitiator`

and the JdbcLockRegistry:

`org.springframework.integration.jdbc.lock.JdbcLockRegistry`

and I'm seeing an issue where non-leader nodes are making database calls every 100ms.

I think I can see what's going on. The leader initiator enters a tight loop when the lock isn't held:

```
while (isRunning()) {
    ...
    // We always try to acquire the lock, in case it expired
    boolean acquired = this.lock.tryLock(LockRegistryLeaderInitiator.this.heartBeatMillis,
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (!this.locked) {
        if (acquired) {
            // Success: we are now leader
            this.locked = true;
            handleGranted();
        }
        else if (isPublishFailedEvents()) {
            publishFailedToAcquire();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The timeout on the `tryLock(...)` call controls the speed at which this code loops by blocking for the period of one heartbeat if the lock cannot be acquired.

The problem occurs in the way that tryLock is written in of some of the LockRegistry implementations.  Take the JdbcLockRegistry for example:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        while (!(acquired = doLock()) && System.currentTimeMillis() < expire) { //NOSONAR
            Thread.sleep(100); //NOSONAR
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

The tryLock method will spin, repeatedly making DB requests every 100ms until the timeout expires. So whilst a lock initiator does not hold a lock it will repeatedly make calls every 100ms ad infinitum.

I've managed to address the issue with the following change to the LockRegistryLeaderInitiator `call()` method:

```
while (isRunning()) {
    try {
        ...
        //We always try to acquire the lock, in case it expired
        boolean acquired = this.lock.tryLock(); // # Make a single attempt to acquire the lock
        if (!this.locked) {
            if (acquired) {
                // Success: we are now leader
                this.locked = true;
                handleGranted();
            } else if (isRunning()) {
                // Wait before trying again.
                Thread.sleep(LockRegistryLeaderInitiator.this.heartBeatMillis); // # Make the heartbeat an explicit thread sleep.
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Is this behaviour by design or a bug?

Edit:
The LockRegistryLeaderInitiator has two configuration properties to control the responsiveness of the election:

```
/**
 * Time in milliseconds to wait in between attempts to re-acquire the lock, once it is
 * held. The heartbeat time has to be less than the remote lock expiry period, if
 * there is one, otherwise other nodes can steal the lock while we are sleeping here.
 * If the remote lock does not expire, or if you know it interrupts the current thread
 * when it expires or is broken, then you can extend the heartbeat to Long.MAX_VALUE.
 */
private long heartBeatMillis = DEFAULT_HEART_BEAT_TIME;

/**
 * Time in milliseconds to wait in between attempts to acquire the lock, if it is not
 * held. The longer this is, the longer the system can be leaderless, if the leader
 * dies. If a leader dies without releasing its lock, the system might still have to
 * wait for the old lock to expire, but after that it should not have to wait longer
 * than the busy wait time to get a new leader. If the remote lock does not expire, or
 * if you know it interrupts the current thread when it expires or is broken, then you
 * can reduce the busy wait to zero.
 */
private long busyWaitMillis = DEFAULT_BUSY_WAIT_TIME;
```

...and it seems like the busyWaitMillis should be involved when a lock is not held ant can't be acquired, but it appears not to be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there's an argument for making it configurable; but it's a trade off between responsiveness and DB activity. If the delay is too long, you might never get the lock.

Personally, I am not a fan of that implementation, especially with JDBC.

Feel free to open a [JIRA 'Improvement' issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT) to make the sleep configurable.

Contributions are welcome.